# C preprocessor: include based on define

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

How can I include a file or another, based on the value of a defined string?

This doesn't work:

```
#define VAR VALUE_A

#if VAR == "VALUE_A"
    #include "a.h"
#elif VAR == "VALUE_B"
    #include "b.h"
#endif
```

If it's important, I'm not actually defining `VAR`, I'm passing it down from the command-line via `gcc -D NAME=VALUE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `==` operator does not compare strings.  But you have a couple of other options to configure your includes.  In addition to the solutions already mentioned in other answers, I like this one because I think it is quite self-explanatory.

```
/* Constant identifying the "alpha" library. */
#define LIBRARY_ALPHA 1

/* Constant identifying the "beta" library. */
#define LIBRARY_BETA 2

/* Provide a default library if the user does not select one. */
#ifndef LIBRARY_TO_USE
#define LIBRARY_TO_USE LIBRARY_ALPHA
#endif

/* Include the selected library while handling errors properly. */
#if LIBRARY_TO_USE == LIBRARY_ALPHA
#include <alpha.h>
#elif LIBRARY_TO_USE == LIBRARY_BETA
#define BETA_USE_OPEN_MP 0  /* You can do more stuff than simply include a header if needed. */
#include <beta.h>
#else
#error "Invalid choice for LIBRARY_TO_USE (select LIBRARY_ALPHA or LIBRARY_BETA)"
#endif
```

Your users can now compile with:

```
$ cc -DLIBRARY_TO_USE=LIBRARY_BETA whatever.c
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` for conditional includes.

```
#ifdef VALUE_A
  #include "a.h"
#endif

#ifdef VALUE_B
  #include "b.h"
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

The closest possilibility I can think of is to utilize third form of `#include` directive (C11 §6.10.2/4), namely define `VAR` with value, that holds actual header filename:

```
#define VAR "a.h"
```

then just use the following:

```
#include VAR
```

Comment: +1 Why the down-vote? I would have also suggested this myself if 
@GrzegorzSzpetkowski wouldn't have been faster.  This is a very flexible technique that is especially useful to provide hooks in libraries.